# blender axis rotation in its center point

Tags: 3d, rotation, blender, collada

I exported this 3D rotating cube, but I can't make to rotate  only on the 3 axis, I mean the cube rotates in all axis but not in the center of the screen goes to the edge and sometimes out of the view, I need to be fixed in the middle of the screen and rotates on the 3 axis center point. Any help is more than welcome.

Comment: What is the "3 axis"? The Z-axis? You can only fix the object at a 3D world coordinate, not a (2D) screen coordinate.

Comment: I need to rotate in the center point of the cube, now the cube is rotation in the center but all over the screen I want to be fixed in the center of the screen and rotate by user input, when I say center of the screen I mean if open in preview for example must be in the center of the screen and rotate in the 3 axis from the center of the cube.

Comment: Sounds like your [object origin](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/origin.html) may be in the wrong place. Set the origin back to geometry and try exporting again.

Comment: Could it be the origin of the object does not lie within the object itself?

Answer (score 4):

I think the center of the object is shifted. Then, all the rotations that you will make are based on that center.

In order to change the center, place the object in the center of the screen. Be sure that you are working on the "Object Mode". Then, press Ctrl + A and then choose "Location". Try to rotate now. The center of the rotation should be placed in the center of the screen. 
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

press `r+z` (if you want to rotate the about z axis) and if you want to rotate about y axis press    `r+y` and so on.

press twice on r to move to trackball rotation mode.

P.S : Your question is bit vague, assuming this would help you.

Comment: I already tried still the same, if I open the colada file with preview on the mac, the model rotate outside of it center, instead of rotating in itself, rotates in another "center" and doing this the object rotates outside of the view. I need the model to rotate only in the center of the page.